# Hill Climbing Search - 8 queens

Tags: search-algorithms

[image]

In that picture, I am having trouble counting why there are 17 pairs of queens. I can only count 14. I counted 10 diagonal pairs and 5 horizontal pairs. Can someone please elaborate on this?

I am not exactly sure how it was numbered, but I believe the numbers on the board represent the new number of pairs that are attacking each other if a queen in that column were to move to that square.

Comment: This picture is so confusing, how was it numbered? what is all about 17? Could you expand the description of the problem?

Comment: Ok, first there are not 17 queens but stated as 17 pairs of queens attacking each other (you have confusing description), and second - this question started as hill climbing, but are you really asking to help you count attacking queens in the blue picture. I counted out of curiosity, I see 17, what next? You have too small count of diagonals.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request to count features of a particular diagram, not a question about computer science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
5 - Horizontal attacks
9 - Diagonal attacks of slope -1
3 - Diagonal attacks of slope +1
-
Total 17 pairs of queens attacking each other.
```

And yes, the numbers in each square correspond to number of attacking pairs of the queen if the queen in the corresponding column is moves to that location.